# Faster sort of NSMutableArray of MPMediaItems? Code Review

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I'm a couple weeks into iOS programming, and have lots to learn. I've got a sort of an NSMutableArray containing MPMediaItems working, but it's about 10 seconds slow with a sort of 1200 items and I'm looking for an approach that would be faster.

My ultimate goal is to have an array of MPMediaItemCollection items, each representing an album. I can't get this from an MPMediaQuery (as far as I know) because I need to get the songs from a playlist. So I'm sorting the songs I get from a specific playlist ("Last 4 months") and will then build my own array of collections. As I say, the approach below works but is very slow. Even if I sort only by the MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, it still takes about 4 seconds (iPhone 4S).

EDIT: I should mention that I tried sort descriptors, but I can't get the key to work. E.g.

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle" ascending:YES];
```

This return an error of

```
[<MPConcreteMediaItem 0x155e50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle.
```

The Code

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playlists = [query collections];
NSMutableArray *songArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *playlist in playlists) {
    NSString *playlistName = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    NSLog (@"%@", playlistName);
    if ([playlistName isEqualToString:@"Last 4 months"]) {

        /* replaced this code with a mutable copy
        NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
        for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
            [songArray addObject:song]; 
        }
        */
        // the following replaces the above for-loop
        songArray = [[playlist items] mutableCopy ];

        [songArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            NSString *first1 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
            NSString *second1 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];

            NSString *first2 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID];
            NSString *second2 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID];

            NSString *first3 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber];
            NSString *second3 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber];

            NSString *first = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%03d",first1,first2, [first3 intValue]];
            NSString *second = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%03d",second1,second2, [second3 intValue]];

            return [first compare:second]; 
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: 1200 items in a for-loop.  You're lucky to even get the 10 and 4 seconds respectively!

Comment: What would be a better way to get all the items in the MPMediaItemCollection into an NSMutableArray than the for loop? But even forgetting the for-loop, the sort only happens once and still takes a long time.

Comment: use `[songs mutableCopy]` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggestion of @cdelacroix I reimplemented my comparison block to cascade the three sort keys, only checking lower order keys if the higher order keys were the same. This resulted in a more than 50% reduction in execution time of the sort. Still, it's not as fast as I would like, so if anyone has a better answer, please post it.

Here are old times vs. new times (1221 items):

4S executionTime = 10.8, executionTime = 4.7

3GS executionTime = 21.6, executionTime = 9.3

Interestingly, the switch from a for-loop to a mutableCopy for the array copy did not seem to improve things. If anything, mutableCopy was perhaps a 10th of a second slower (anyone done any benchmarking on mutableCopy?). But I left the change in because it is so much cleaner looking.

Lastly, note the check for album title == nil. Be aware that compare thinks anything with a nil value is always NSOrderedSame as anything else. One album in the list didn't have a title set, and this screwed up the sort order without this check.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playlists = [query collections];
NSMutableArray *songArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *playlist in playlists) {
    NSString *playlistName = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    NSLog (@"%@", playlistName);
    if ([playlistName isEqualToString:@"Last 4 months"]) {

        songArray = [[playlist items] mutableCopy ];

        [songArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            NSComparisonResult compareResult;

            NSString *first1 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
            if(first1 == nil) first1 = @" "; // critical because compare will match nil to anything and result in NSOrderedSame
            NSString *second1 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
            if(second1 == nil) second1 = @" ";  // critical because compare will match nil to anything and result in NSOrderedSame
            compareResult = [first1 compare:second1];

            if (compareResult == NSOrderedSame) {
                NSString *first2 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID];
                NSString *second2 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID];
                compareResult = [first2 compare:second2];
                if(compareResult == NSOrderedSame) {
                    NSString *first3 = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber];
                    NSString *second3 = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber];
                    compareResult = [first3 compare:second3];
                }
            }
            return compareResult;
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I thought it important to clarify why the OPs sort code didn't work so that anyone who comes across this code isn't put off of using NSSortDescriptors.

The code:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle" ascending:YES];
```

Should be:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle ascending:YES];
```

as MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle holds the name of the key.

I have used this code many times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [sort descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html).

Then your sort will be as simple as `return [songs sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];` and should also be much faster.

EDIT: according to the OP, the MPMediaItem class is not KVC-compliant, so I'm retiring the answer.

Comment: I tried sort descriptors, but it failed with an error of [<MPConcreteMediaItem 0x155e50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle. This with a NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle" ascending:YES];

Comment: Hu, I was not expecting a new class to be non-KVC-compliant. Well if you don't find anything relevant in the Media Player framework documentation, you can still optimize your comparison method by comparing each term one by one (key after key) and returning as soon as a comparison result is not NSOrderedSame. This will avoid building a string for that and should be better performance-wise. I hope someone will come with a better and Cocoa-friendlier way, though.