# MPMediaItem this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

Im trying to retrieve the track number of the songs in my iPod library.

Basically I've queried for all the albums as follows:

```
NSArray *albums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery].collections;
```

Retrieved the an album:

```
MPMediaItemCollection *album = self.albums[0];
```

Iterate through the songs and try to log the track number

```
for (MPMediaItem *mediaItem in self.album.items)
{
    NSLog(@"Track Number %@", [mediaItem valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount]);
}
```

But this gives me the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<MPConcreteMediaItem 0x1cd818d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is 
not key value coding-compliant for the key albumTrackCount.'
```

If I try other keys such as `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`, `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle` or `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist` works fine. Is there something I'm missing as to why I can't access the `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090359/faster-sort-of-nsmutablearray-of-mpmediaitems-code-review

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used `valueForKey:` that's why the error happening. Use `valueForProperty:` like:

```
NSLog(@"Track Number %@", [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount]);
```

In the [MPMediaItem Class Referece](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) Apple says that:

> You obtain metadata for a media item by calling the valueForProperty
>   method with these property keys.

Comment: @EdwardHuynh: with pleasure :)